# /system/lib/libposprinter.so" not found | POS Printing

Tags: android, thermal-printer, pos

I am working with an Android POS System Application, And i have integrated the **THERMAL PRINT SDK**

When i initiate to do the printing, getting the below error -

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library /system/lib/libposprinter.so" not found

I am stuck in this issue.

Please Help!

Comment: I do not know how anyone other than the device manufacturer/SDK developer can help you here. The SDK is expecting a native library to exist in a particular spot on this hardware, and it doesn't. An app cannot put a native library in that spot, so the SDK must be expecting it to have been pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with the epson library around 6 months ago but not sure if its the same problem. I have a feeling your device is trying to use one of the native libraries that doesn't exist due to epson not providing it. You can kinda force your app to fallback to a provided native library folder in order for it to work

I ended up restricting my app to only armeabi-v7a and x86 arch types. It did make the app incompatible on some devices but wasn't an issue for our use case.

I had the following setup

1. Ensure the lib is added to `libs/ePOS2-2.5.1.a.jar` and referenced in gradle like `compile files('libs/ePOS2-2.5.1.a.jar')` or whatever
2. Add the appropriate native libs like `src/main/jiniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libepos2.so` and `src/main/jiniLibs/x86/libepos2.so`
3. update your gradle buildtypes to restrict the abis like

.

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true  // Deobfuscation mapping file located at app/build/outputs/mapping/release/
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
}
```

I used this as a guide https://android.jlelse.eu/controlling-apk-size-when-using-native-libraries-45c6c0e5b70a